# How to parse HTML files in a Google Cloud Function?

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have a cloud function that i a trying to display some data on a html page when ever a user loads the entry point,
This works very fine when i run it on local host, but when it is online in the google cloud platform, the html file does not parse successfully, i get this error

" {"status":"error","code":500,"message":"Parsing Template Error","data":{"Op":"open","Path":"index.html","Err":2}}
Function panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference"

Here is my entry point function,

```
  func (c *Ctlr) Home(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    Log := prettylogs.Get()
    ctlr := InitController(*Log)
    defer Log.Exit(Log.Enter())
 
    t, err := template.ParseFiles("index.html")
    if err != nil {
        Log.Error("Parsing Template Error: ", err)
        sendResponse(w, r, http.StatusInternalServerError, "Parsing Template Error", err)
    }

    // Call the internal function here which will return the Template data
    Data, err := ctlr.GetTemplateData()
    if err != nil {
        sendResponse(w, r, http.StatusInternalServerError, "Error in fetching data", err)
    }

    type Transfer struct {
        Data        []AnaysisData
        Account     Accounts        
    }
    
    var allData Transfer
    allData.Data = Data
    allData.Account = setSession(r)
        
    err = t.Execute(w, allData)
    if err != nil {
        Log.Error("Template execution error: ", err)
        sendResponse(w, r, http.StatusInternalServerError, "Template Execution Error", err)
    }
    

    return
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIRC, the issue is that the Cloud Functions deployment puts your deployed code in `serverless_function_source_code` subdirectory, including the template file, while the `main.go` (and thus the working directory is the root. When `main.go` invokes the handler, the reference to `index.html` is wrong (`./index.html`) and should be `(./serverless_function_source_code/index.html`).

See [File system](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#functions-concepts-filesystem-go).

If you're using Go Modules (`go.mod`) (I think this is different if you're using GOPATH), then you should reference the template from that path, i.e.

```golang
t, err := template.ParseFiles("serverless_function_source_code/index.html")
```